# Jenkins - Exception while cleaning project using clean command

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have tried to clean project using command 'clean' from Jenkins and i am getting below error..

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable. -> [Help 1]

I could see clean plugin in m2 and i am not sure which dependency is missing in it. Can anyone help to resolve it?

Comment: You are trying to access central repository via http instead of https ? Why are you trying to access central via http ?

Comment: as of now we are doing manual build with this one only and no issues we could see. while trying to automate using Jenkins we are facing this problem. I will update and try once.

Comment: As i checked in our app code, i do not find this url. we are using mvn 2.2.1 and i guess this configuration is coming with it.  Do you have any idea about this?